# Can we pour slab even if the bricks below it are not leveled?

Tags: foundation, slab, footings, level

So we were about to pour concrete on on top of 3 layers of bricks that is already done.

I always ask the guy who manages and he always say its leveled , so today I went my self and we all checked but they are not leveled at all. Here is image showing which angels are high which are low.
[image]

I am not sure what is the best way to solve this now, Options I though of is

1. we just fill with concrete whatever is missing to make it level, before the plan was to do 7cm slub but now the high angle C would be around 22 cm.
2. we make concrete only above bricks to level it , fill with sand then pure the 7cm slub on top of all.

I am really shocked how can they just build with this big error , and now not sure what is best way to fix it ?

Comment: It is obvious you have not poured concrete adding sand on top would not be the best thing it would be better in my opinion to fill the void with concrete, 3 layers of brick sounds like a good base but a little variation in the base is no big deal.

Comment: Usually do not want to pay for extra concrete unless you need it.  Ask contractor if they are willing to pay the extra or fix their mistake.

Comment: Angle is 15cm higher than A , We need double the concrete that was planed if we fill all. And is it the best solution to just fill it with concrete ?

Comment: One is probably not paying for extra if this is coming in a truck; extra only counts if hand-mixed. Maybe the OP can clarify. (I hope the contractor is going to parge the blockwork to hide the sloppiness.)

Comment: I love it when people say sloppy or paying extra when the cost of making a perfectly level base would cost many times more and is normal construction for such work.

Comment: @EdBeal you mean to make it perfectly level should cost much more ? not if they have done when doing bricks . right ?

Comment: It cost more to make the base perfectly flat and it won’t be a problem at all spending time on the concrete and the finish is where you really want your contractor to spend time with a 3 level of brick you have a good base don’t sweat the minor variations in the case of concrete it won’t matter or really cost more

Comment: How did you measure the "un-levelness" of the brickwork?

Comment: self leveling concrete

Comment: we measured with Water leveling

Comment: @EdBeal, I agree most likely thats what we will do, anther guy suggested we do something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ck03oRIw1Pg , where we put wood and level it then we raise the ground in heigh part with stones and we then fill with concrete

Comment: That is setup for a monolithic pour where the foundation is poured all at one time with the slab did you notice the large divots is areas this is why I said the out of level or divots really don’t matter 6 cm or 3 “ in small areas is not a big deal.

Comment: At least one of your measurements is wrong. There's no way C could be the same 6 cm below both B and D,when B and D are themselves separated by another 6 cm. Please double-check your numbers,as it's not entirely impossible that all the measurements are affected by some systematic error.

Comment: @TooTea, Thats totally correct, how i didn't notice that.. will check numbers 2moro again

Comment: @EdBeal C is lower than A by 15cm , not only 6 cm.